# How to create a PostGIS layer using QGIS API?

Tags: postgis, qgis

I want to create a new PostGIS layer and save changes made to it.

Presently, I am connecting Python to PostGIS using psycopg2 but I want to know whether there is any QGIS API function available.

Note: I am able to open an existing PostGIS layer, but I don't know how to create a new one.

Answer (score 1):

"How to create a postgis PostGIS layer in qgis" > You could have been more clear before! It took time to me to write my first answer (deleted since).

You can have a look on [that online workshop](http://www.qgisworkshop.org/html/workshop/index.html) and particularly on [that section](http://www.qgisworkshop.org/html/workshop/python_in_qgis_tutorial2.html#adding-a-postgis-layer).

I guess you already know the [QGIS api doc](http://doc.qgis.org/)!

Comment: Thanks Simo.. and I regret for being not clear to the question.

Comment: Don't worry... Hope the new provided link would be helpful